# Локализация carbon

Tags: laravel, локализация, русификация, carbon

Как локализовать carbon в laravel 5?
Нашел инструкцию для 4-ой, но для 5-ой не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

```
CarbonInterval::setLocale('ru');
```

[Доки](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

[Ссылка](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon) на Git локализации там есть больше инфы.